# Looking for multi-select, scrollable, List component for Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap

I can't find a scrollable, multi-select List component for Bootstrap; anybody know of one?

Select2 components are great but I want the list expanded at first, not a dropdown.

Bonus if it works handily with Text input component for searching/filtering.

Thanks for any helpful tips!

Answer (score 5):

If you are looking for a 2 column select layout, check [this out](https://github.com/rabihkodeih/bootstrap-transfer)

If you are looking for a multiselect dropdown - Check [here](https://github.com/davidstutz/bootstrap-multiselect)

Comment: Nice components, but the mockup from our designer is showing a list component, not a dropdown.

Comment: the 2nd and 3rd links do that

Comment: Perhaps I'm not seeing it in the demo examples on the site but everything with this component is based on a select input. Meaning, to trigger seeing the List you have to click the select. I'm looking for a JSP page that shows an already expanded List component (Flex) or Grid/Table (HTML).

Answer (score 4):

To make the dropdown scrollable add the following css

```
.multiselect-container {
    height: 200px;  
    overflow-x: hidden;
    overflow-y: scroll;  
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[Bootstrap Dual Listbox](http://www.virtuosoft.eu/code/bootstrap-duallistbox/) use two lists to manage the selections.

In your HTML doc:

```
<select name="duallistbox[]" multiselect>
    <option value="1">Option 1</option>
    <option value="2">Option 2</option>
    <option value="3">Option 3</option>
    <option value="4">Option 4</option>
    ...
    <option value="10">Option 10</option>
</select>
```

In your JS script:

```
$('select[name="duallistbox[]"]').bootstrapDualListbox();
```

Which results in:
[Image](http://new.tinygrab.com/07a0e338d13d2da06ffd66752641578c20f3181a5e.png)

Answer (score 1):

I've recently created very simple jQuerUI [plugin](http://jsfiddle.net/voroninp/B2s5z/) which mimics multiselection functionality by toggling `.active` class on the elements.

```
$(selector).multiselect("selection")
```

returns an array of indices of the children elemens having class `.active`.

Scrolling and other styling is done by applying corresponding CSS.